# Image map doesn't work all the time

Tags: html, css

Image map works on other documents except this one. Is there any error? Or is there any reason Chrome doesn't load it?

```
<html>
<head>
```

CSS

```
<style>
body {
      background-color:rgb(221,160,221);
}
h1,p {
      font-family:courier;
      color:white;
}
h1 {
    text-align:center;
}
</style>
</head>
```

Body

```
<body>
<h1> Find the Difference </h1>
<hr color="white">
<p> Welcome to this game <br>
Hope you have a frustrating time finding the difference... </p>
```

The images

```
<img src="Dod2.jpg" height="522" width="368" alt="Please change your browser as it doesn't support this file type"> 
<img src="Dod.jpg" height="522" width="368" alt="Please change your browser as it doesn't support this file type" usemap="#dod">
```

Image Map

```
<map name="dod">
<area shape="poly" coords="523,194,477,215,480,234,481,254,493,268,521,228,540,218,556,213,550,201" alt="Sorry, your browser doesn't support this function." href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beak" target="_blank">
</map>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Validate your code: https://validator.w3.org/nu/

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/area: _“For a rect or rectangle shape, the coords value is two x,y pairs: left, top, right, and bottom. ”_

Answer (score 1):

First of all `<area>` coords does not correspond to its shape. For `shape="rect"` there must be only 4 coordinates see on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/area#attr-coords).

Another problem is that the area coordinates seems going beyond the size of the image. In your example image size is 368x522. But even the first pairs of coordinates (X,Y) from coords attribute (X=523, Y=194) already outside the picture. So it seems that this map just does not correspond to you image. Try to generate a new map.

Comment: I wasn't able to find a way to know the coords, so i used a website to help me. This worked out before. Thanks for the help!